# vsftpd listen on multiple listen_address but not on all

Tags: linux, ftp, vsftpd

I'm looking for a way to configure vsftpd to use multiple listen_address IPs. I'm aware that if I set it to the default, it will listen on all available interface IPs, but that's not what I'm looking for.

Is there a way to configure something like this?

```
listen_address=192.168.1.3,192.168.1.4,192.168.1.5
```

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the machine is multi homed with 2 or more IP addresses, then you can setup multiple vsftpd services. Make a copy of the vsftpd.conf, adjust the *listen_address* to the additional IP address. Start another vsftpd daemon using the new config file.

Comment: ok, this would be the last resort.. but I wanted to check if it is possible with one instance.

Comment: obviously this is the only way to accomplish such a setup... thx

Answer (score 1):

I have not idea about vsftpd exactly, but what about listen all interfaces and add iptables rule to prevent access from some of them?

like iptables -A INPUT -i ... -j DROP

Comment: The issue is, that I need other vsftpd instances on other IP addresses, so it's not about allow/deny of certain IPs.